# how to transfer users organization all together on grafana

Tags: permissions, grafana, organization

I am the server admin and I get over 2000 users in my original organization on grafana.

Now I create a new org and I wanted to transfer them to the new one but according to the grafana website I can only click into every users profile and add the new org to them one by one.

Is there an easier way to do that?

the reason I wanna get some of them transferred is that the original org got some private high-secured data sources that they are not allowed to see so the original one is for those higher levels. So if there is another way to accomplish that target, that would also helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to write a script that uses the [Grafana HTTP API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/).

You can loop through a list of users and add them to an organization using the [Organization API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/org/#add-a-new-user-to-the-current-organization).

Comment: where should I write the script to use the API?